# Calling an object after an ajax call returns

Tags: jquery

I built the following object:

```
 var cls = {
    offset : 0,
    onSuccess : function(data) {
        alert(this.offset);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
              $.post(
                  "/ajax",
                  {},
                   cls.onSuccess
               );
     });
});
```

When the ajax returns and `onSuccess` of `cls` is called then I get an alert of `undefined`.

If I just call `cls.onSuccess()` then the alert returns `0` ex expected. Any reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the AJAX function a context for the callback. I would use .ajax() instead of .post() and pass cls as the context:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/ajax",
  context: cls,
  type: "POST",
  success: cls.onSuccess
});
```

Answer (score 2):

don't use "this". it will not refer to what you expect to refer.

use window.alert(cls.offset);

it's quite long to explain, but this should help you.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not your object, `cls`,  anymore. You are passing a function reference, `onSuccess` to the post call.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing just the function, independent of the object.  If you wrap it in a function it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
              $.post(
                  "/ajax",
                  {},
                   function(data){
                      cls.onSuccess(data);
                   }
               );
     });
});
```